# Pipe forward monad operator

Tags: haskell

Is there a built in version of this operator or is there a package that has this operator? Hoogle did not come up with anything.

```
infixl 0 &*
x &* f = fmap f x

getLine &* map toUpper >>= putStrLn
```

Comment: Isn't that just [`<$>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-)?

Comment: @Bakuriu `<$>` has the arguments in the wrong order

Comment: Actually `flip fmap` / `flip <$>`. `lens` [has this by the name `<&>`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Functor+f+%3D%3E+f+a+-%3E+%28a-%3Eb%29+-%3E+f+b+%2Blens). Not with fixity 0 though, which doesn't seem advisable either, IMO.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That was what I was looking for. If you make it an answer I will accept it.